# Using the isnumber() function in Excel and Formatting Issue

Tags: excel

I have a list of values, some being integers and some being non-integers.  I would like to return the values that are integers. My idea:

```
if(ISNUMBER(C1)=TRUE,C1,0)
```

The data is laid out as so

```
88  
Francesc Fabregas  
m  
86  
Andrey Arshavin  
a  
86
```

Therefore I would only return the 88, 86, and 86. 88 is in cell C1.
Update: THE CELLS HAVE THE VALUES STORED IN THEM AS TEXT. HOW MIGHT I CHANGE ALL THE CELLS FORMATTING TO NUMBERS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=IFERROR(--C1,"")
```

It will try to multiply -1*-1 to the value, if it is like a number it will return the number but if not it will error out and return `""`.

[image]

If you are using 2003 or later then use:

```
=IF(ISERR(--C1),"",--C1)
```

---

To do it in place highlight the range and you will see a little box in the upper left corner:

[image]

Hit that button and you will have a drop down list of option.  Choose the "Convert to Number" option.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The NUBMERVALUE() function converts text to numbers. So the formula

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(NUMBERVALUE(D14)), NUMBERVALUE(D14), 0)
```

would turn your data to

```
88
0
0
86
0
0
86
```